Relaxation of Hoeffding's Lemma
Hoeffding's lemma requires that the random variable is bounded almost surely. Are there similar conclusions when the random variable can only be bounded with high probability, such as a binomial one?

In the Hoeffding inequality, without loss of generality we can assume $E(X)=0$ and $a=-1,b=1$, leading to $$k(\lambda)=\log E(e^{\lambda X})\leq  \lambda^2/2.$$ The proof is easy, since if $$X_{\lambda}\sim e^{\lambda x-k(\lambda)}\mu(dx)$$ where $X\sim \mu$ then $k(0)=k'(0)=0$, $k'(\lambda)=E(X_{\lambda})$, $k''(\lambda)$ is the variance of $X_{\lambda}$ and is therefore in $[0,1]$ since $|X|\leq 1.$ As a consequence for $\lambda>0$ $$k(\lambda)=\int_0^{\lambda}k'(t)dt=\int_0^{\lambda}\left(\int_0^t k''(s)ds\right)dt\leq \int_0^{\lambda}tdt=\lambda^2/2.$$ The proof is similar for $\lambda<0.$ I have given the proof to show that the crux is the fact that the variance function of the exponential family generated by $\mu$ is in $[0,1]$. Therefore if you want to generalize with distribution with small tails, this is not enough, since small tails can have big variances. In the other hand, Hoeffding inequality still holds for $\mu$ generating a variance $k''(\lambda)$ bounded by $1,$ which does not necessitate that $\mu$ has bounded support. Example $X\sim N(0,1).$

Yes. This is stated clearly on the wikipedia page:

Hoeffding's lemma [implies] that such variables are subgaussian.

Refer to equivalent definition 5 on the subgaussian wikipedia page:
$$
\operatorname{E} [e^{(X-\operatorname{E}[X])t}] \leq e^{\frac{K^2t^2}{2}}
$$
Thus, any sub-Gaussian variable with $K=1$ respects the Hoeffding inequality. This includes the standard Gaussian, for example.
As noted by Gérard, subgaussian variables must have tails that decrease quite quickly. Indeed, their tail probability decreases in $\exp(-t^2/K_2^2)$ (equivalent definition 1).
